# Изменение цвета у псевдоэлемента CSS

Tags: css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как 1 сторонним классом стилей поменять бэкграунд цвет у предыдущего, включая все его `after`, `before`

Подскажите, как вернее поступить?

```css
.d15 {
  width: 180px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: #bdbdbd;
  position: relative;
}

.d15:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 100%;
  border-width: 20px 0 20px 40px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent #bdbdbd;
}

.success {
  background: #7bf195!important;
  border-color: #7bf195!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="success d15"></div><br>
<div class="d16"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если я правильно понял о чём вы

```css
.d15 {
  width: 180px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: #bdbdbd;
  position: relative;
}

.d15:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 100%;
  border-width: 20px 0 20px 40px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent #bdbdbd;
}

.success {
  background: #7bf195;
}

.success::after {
  border-color: transparent #7bf195;
}
```

```html
<div class="success d15"></div><br>
<div class="d16"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!